# Entity Framework Database First get only active rows by default

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

We recently added a new boolean column ACTIVE to our Employee table. Therefore, when a user wants to delete an employee in the table, the record will be "soft deleted" (ACTIVE field will be set to false instead of the row being removed completely.)

However, the table is being used everywhere in the app and we don't want to add .Where(employee => employee.ACTIVE) every time we query the table. Is there a way we can get these ACTIVE rows by default, maybe put the Where clause at the root level somewhere? (we don't care about inactive employees in the live app, but we need those records in the database.)

We use Database First EF, so we won't be able to use the same Soft Delete strategies in Code First (Interceptors).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a bit old, but check out this link https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/29/missing-ef-feature-workarounds-filters/

Comment: if EF does not solve it, create a view on top of your table that only lists active ones and change out the usage against that of a view. if you use EF to insert/update/delete into that table I would not recommend that.

Comment: Please search for "Entity Framework" + "soft delete". You'll find many alternatives. Also, the options depend on the EF version.

Comment: It also seems to be a feature that is getting added to EF Core.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters

Comment: Another [soft delete link](https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/soft-deleting-entities-cleanly-using-entity-framework-6-interceptors.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Dynamic Filters](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters) (which is a pretty good library that basically uses DbInterceptors).

We do the same thing. Here's example code of how we set it up to enforce tenants in a multi-tenant environment:

```
        modelBuilder.Filter("ChmPeople_ChurchId",
            (IChurchDataPrivileged entity, int churchId) => entity.ChurchId == churchId || entity.ChurchId == 0,
            () => AuthenticatedUser?.ChurchId ?? 0);
```

ChurchId = tenant id, so all queries to the database are automatically filtered by the currently logged in tenant's ID.